# failed to generate workload certificate: create certificate istio ingress

Tags: amazon-eks, istio

I am getting below error in istio-ingress pods.

```
2023-09-10T05:18:55.390302Z     warn    sds     failed to warm certificate: failed to generate workload certificate: create certificate: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing: dial tcp 10.100.19.43:15012: i/o timeout"

    kubectl get --raw /api/v1/namespaces/istio-system/services/https:istiod:https-webhook/proxy/inject -v4

I0909 22:59:29.079159   21513 helpers.go:246] server response object: [{
  "metadata": {},
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "the server rejected our request for an unknown reason",
  "reason": "BadRequest",
  "details": {
    "causes": [
      {
        "reason": "UnexpectedServerResponse",
        "message": "no body found"
      }
    ]
```

Initially I got below error,

```
Error from server (ServiceUnavailable): error trying to reach service: dial tcp 172.44.30.55:15017: connect: connection timed out
```

I fixed this issue by adding security group inbound rules in eks node security group with source as eks cluster security group and allowing all traffic and port
[image]

But now I seeing error as below,
2023-09-10T05:18:55.390302Z     warn    sds     failed to warm certificate: failed to generate workload certificate: create certificate: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing: dial tcp 10.100.19.43:15012: i/o timeout"

Although I have allowed all traffic from eks cluster security group to eks node security group so eks cluster can reach istiod. Not sure why I the error..